# linux shell script to fetch a <latest file> of <particular name> in a folder

Tags: linux, shell

I'm enhancing my linux script, I have a folder with lots of files of different dates, I want to fetch a latest file starting with a particular name.

For ex.
I have below list of files in a folder I need latest file of name Subnetwork_RAN in a folder:

```
Subnetwork_PCC_11Dec2022UTC0500
Subnetwork_RAN_12Dec2022UTC0500
Subnetwork_RAN_13Dec2022UTC0500
Subnetwork_PCC_13Dec2022UTC0500
```

Output will be file name Subnetwork_RAN_13Dec2022UTC0500

I tried to build a linux shell script to get latest file of particular name.

Comment: Any chance of changing the date format to ISO 8601? That would make this a trivial task.

Comment: hi briffen actually i wanted to fetch lastest file of particular name  from a particular name  like latest file name starting with "abc" from a particular folder

Comment: I understand that. It doesn’t answer my question, though.

Comment: i cant change the fine name

Comment: So you mean by _latest_ a file with highest timestamp in its name, and don't refer to the modification time of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has a rather simple `awk` solution:

```
ls -tl | awk ' $9 ~ /Subnetwork_RAN/ {print $9; exit;}'
```

`ls -tl` outputs a long listing of the current directory, sorted by time (newest first).

This output is piped to `awk` which (line-by-line) looks for a filename containing the required string. The first time it finds one, it prints the filename and exits.

Note, this assumes (as in your example) that the filename contains no white space. If it does, you need to modify the print statement to print the substring of the line `$0` beginning with your string, to the end of the line.

If your string might be repeated in more recent filenames but not at the start, the regex condition can be modified to select only filenames where your string is at the start `$9~/^Subnetwork_RAN/`

Comment: You are making the strong assumptions that sorting by time and sorting by the date in the filename gives you the same result. OP should be aware of that.

Comment: @mik1904 perhaps you are making a wrong assumption about how -t works. The procedure is tested and works, ordering by year, then date, then time. Newest first.

Comment: afaik, `-t` uses the file modification time for sorting. Ain't that true?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have a file called `test.txt` with the filenames you showed. Then in bash you can do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="_"} $0 ~/Subnetwork_RAN/ {printf "%s ",$0; system("date +%s -d " $3)}' asd | sort -rn -k 2 | head -1 | cut -d " " -f 1
```

Output:

`Subnetwork_RAN_13Dec2022UTC0500`

Some explanation:

- `$0 ~ /Subnetwork_RAN/` matches all the lines containing the sub-string "Subnetwork_RAN"
- The bash command `date` can recognize the date format like this 13Dec2022UTC0500 and transform it in a timestamp (`date +%s`)
- `sort` sorts numerically in reverse order based on the second field (timestamp output of awk `system` call)
- `head` gives the first line, i.e., the most recent
- `cut` takes only the first field given a field separator equal to " ". The first field is the full filename (`printf` call in awk)